# javascript onclick event over iframe does not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

I have a page and external iframe on the page.
I need to catch an onclick event over iframe. Iframe is from different domain (e.g. youtube ...) So i cannot use .contents() method of Jquery.

Please help me to write jquery or native js code to handle this event. I saw [solution](http://jsbin.com/wuberiduwe/edit?html,css,js,output)  but it requires an div wrapper over frame and i can't do that.

Comment: You can not catch the click if it is in another domain and you can not add a layer over it. Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Can you explain why the div wrapper solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you share code of div wrapper which you are trying and doesn't work for you?

Comment: @amol: the div wrapper code is linked in the question.